# Composite primary key, whats the best way to identify this resource with REST?

Tags: java, rest, jpa

I have an entity `ProjectEmployee` which represents a ternary association. The composition of two of its fields `Employee` and `Project`  has to be unique:

```
@Entity
@Data
@IdClass(ProjectEmployeeId.class)
public class ProjectEmployee {

  @Id
  @ManyToOne
  private Project project;

  @Id
  @ManyToOne
  private Employee employee;

  @ManyToOne
  private ProjectEmployeeRole projectEmployeeRole;
}
```

Im using REST and i would like to identify each resource with an unique identifier. I can´t do it for `ProjectEmployee`, because this entity does not have one unique identifier. Whats the best solution for this? Do i always have to send two parameters to identify this resource like this?

GET:

```
../projectemployees/{proejctId}/{employeeId}
```

This would identify the resource, but is there any way to do it with just one identifier instead of two?

Comment: I would strongly advice to use an artificial (i.e. not user-visible) primary key.

Comment: Hm, do you mean that i should use something like UUIDs to identify my resource from outside the application? So i could keep having the double primary key i have right now and just add an unique column "uuid" which i could use to identify the resource in rest? `../projectemployees/{uuid}` ?

Comment: I would suggest it the other way around: make the `UUID` the primary key, add the `UNIQUE` constraint to the other two columns. To be honest, I am not sure I would expose the relationship through a REST API. I would suggest using a HATEOAS-like approach: let the `Employee` return a list of references (uris) to the projects s/he is part of; let the Project return a list of references (uris) of the employees participating in the project.

Answer (score 0):

"REST" doesn't care what you use as an identifier, so long as it conforms to the production rules described by RFC 3986.

```
/cee03013-7761-465f-a71c-791450c8e785
```

Is a perfectly satisfactory URI.

Any information encoded into the URI is done by the origin server at its own discretion.

Any spelling that allows you, the server, to correctly associate the request with the intended resource and its representations, is *fine*.